# Boot problems, win8,win10,ubuntu, efi, gpt

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, boot-repair, gpt

I apologize as this I'm sure has been asked several times,it just seems I can't figure it out,  I have win8, win10 and ubuntu, I installed debian once, before win8 I had win7, well, I add my boot repair log, any help/advice/explanation as to what can be done is much appreciated,

[boot repair diagnostics text](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DbgyzWt67Z/)

If possible I would like to know how to reinstall/the specifications (fat32 or what) and where to install/reinstall grub to solve a problem if this happens in the future

Comment: You have all drives as gpt. But Boot-Repair says it sees a BIOS/MBR version of Windows. Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt. Grub & WIndows typically share one ESP, but you can have an ESP on every drive,. preferably gpt. You have BIOS boot loaders in MBR of sda & sdb, those should be ignored & only boot in UEFI mode. With Boot-Repair always reinstall/install grub to a drive that has an ESP.

Comment: Can there be a fat32, efi, 100mb on each drive to avoid problems ia it recommended ? What steps could I take to be able to boot to win 10, win8, ubuntu ? Should I delete the efi partition ? Create a new one ? I'm sorry to ask so many questions I'm a n00b on terms of these new hdd gpt configuration, I think my bios is also old I also saw an error about a vfat file system. I used to partition disk when acronis safe zone and os selector was popular.. this is new :(

Comment: Or is there a way or a program that can "clean" the mess ? Thanks beforhand

Comment: If you delete the ESP, you will not be able to boot. I like an ESP on every drive, but then Ubuntu installer Ubiquity only installs to the first drive's ESP. I have to do a work around. If you have UEFI, system not real old. This is a question & answer site. You are supposed to ask one question and then get one answer that others then can find and use  if they have same issue.

Comment: My apologies, my question would be, what is the recommended course of action in my scenario y I want to see a menu with options win8,win10,ubuntu when I boot my computer ? what should I edit/delete/add ?

Comment: They all need to be installed in UEFI boot mode. Windows also only creates one entry in UEFI and newer install adds its files & updates BCD to dual boot Windows. Then grub only sees one Windows & the that Windows has choice. Grub also only boots working Windows or fast start up off, and not needing chkdsk. If you have each Windows on separate drives with its  own ESP, then grub can find each. But Windows will want to default to just one ESP also. https://askubuntu.com/questions/653101/boot-repair-windows-not-listed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, many thanks for the information shared in the answers section, I was able to recover win10, not win8 but I can now dual boot win10 and ubuntu, I used diskgenius, to create the MS reserved 16mb partition, 100 mb efi fylesystem partition and used a recovery boot cd/dvd tool and used the command:

`bcdboot C:\Windows /l en-us /s k: /f ALL`
disk letters need to be checked first

I found many websites with instructions but I did know what I had to fix, until I fixed all of the above I was able to boot my pc again (did not know windows used 3 partitions,   ms reserverd, efi abd C:), I had to install ubuntu on its own HDD to be sure it was going to boot, many useful commands are found here

[Repair dual boot problems, windows](http://woshub.com/how-to-repair-uefi-bootloader-in-windows-8/)