# How can I dual boot with specific BIOS settings for each OS?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I dual boot Windows 10 on my laptop using GRUB2 and GRUB Customizer. I have a laptop with two GPU's and a "Hybrid Mode" setting in the BIOS. I want to have the option of booting with Hybrid Mode on or off when I choose my OS. I imagine having a list like this:

- Ubuntu
- Windows 10 (RTX 2060)
- Windows 10 (Hybrid Mode)

How can I get it so that Ubuntu always boots with Hybrid Mode set to "on" and then I have two options for Windows depending on if I am planning for gaming or productivity. I found [gfxmode](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/gfxmode.html#gfxmode) in the GRUB manual, but I am not sure whether this will work.

Any tips on how I can find the specific variable names or boot sequence commands to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Windows only dual boots from its BCD entry. And then grub only finds one Wihdows boot entry to try to boot. You  may be able to have two FAT32 partitions with different BCD. Once UEFI boots the one FAT32 flagged as ESP/boot, grub then can find two different Windows installs. UEFI expects one ESP, but grub will let you boot using any file that works. Dual boot two Windows UEFI from grub, two efi partitions.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/653101/boot-repair-windows-not-listed Suggest only temporarily have another ESP for second Windows. So UEFI is ok with only one actual ESP.