# Grub boot Ubuntu, Windows10 and Windows 11

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a working dual boot option on my pc with Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

I have installed a new SSD on this PC and installed a new version of Windows on that new SSD.
When I boot from this new SSD, I can see the new Windows running.

I would like to have a boot option to have 3 options

Can I modify/reconfigure the grub to have 3 boot options in ubuntu to have following options

1.ubuntu
2.Windows 10
3.Windows 10 new version on the new SSD drive

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: Are all installs in UEFI boot mode? Does each Windows has a separate ESP - efi system partition? If so then grub will automatically find two Windows installs. But if when you installed Windows, it saw first install, then it overwrote its /EFI/Microsoft folder & updated BCD to dual boot from one BCS. https://askubuntu.com/questions/653101/boot-repair-windows-not-listed & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2478842

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)